# How to install Java required for closure compiler?

Tags: java, google-closure-compiler, emscripten

I'm trying to build an Emscripten project but I get the following error:

```
shared:WARNING: java does not seem to exist, required for closure compiler, which is optional (define JAVA in /Users/cuinjune/.emscripten if you want it)
shared:ERROR: fatal: closure compiler is not configured correctly
```

I installed JDK but it didn't work.

Based on this link: https://emscripten.org/docs/building_from_source/verify_emscripten_environment.html

I tried `./emsdk install java-7.45-64bit` but it says:

> Error: No tool or SDK found by name 'java-7.45-64bit'.

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: did you run `./emsdk install` as described in the article?

Comment: Did you do a `./emsdk list` first?

Comment: @jbx Yes but `java` doesn't show up in the list. other tools show up instead such as clang, node, spidermonkey...etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Mac? Just install generic OpenJDK or OracleJDK from Oracle website and set JAVA environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that
`JRE !== JDK`
maybe it could help someone.